# Failure time distributions from an uncertain starting point

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reliability

I have a data analysis problem in the laboratory which I think can be reframed as a kind of reliability question.

**Question:**
Suppose a warehouse is filled with light bulbs. The probability distribution of lifetimes of the light bulbs is $P(t)$. Now consider that the light bulbs have unknown ages at time $t=0$ (i.e., they were replaced some time ago, but we can't know exactly when). How long should we expect we have until a light bulb fails?

**Attempt:**
The lifetime of a lightbulb is $t + t'$, where $t$ is the time since we started observing the bulb and $t'$ is the unknown time between installation and the period when we started observing the bulb.

If failure occurs at $t+t'$, we have $\tau = t+t'$ distributed as $P(\tau)$. However, we can only measure the distribution of $t$, i.e. the lifetimes since we started paying attention: call that $O(t)$. Given that we don't know the unknown time that lapsed before we started watching the bulbs, a reflection of our ignorance is to assume this time is a uniform distribution. Since the time $\tau$ is the sum of two random variables, we can conclude
$$ P(\tau) = \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T O(\tau-t) dt.$$

I do not think this is correct since the result diverges if $O(\tau-t)$ is an exponential distribution. I believe the problem is that I assumed $t$ and $t'$, the observed and un-observed times, were independent.

Is this a known problem in reliability theory? Do I have enough information to estimate the probability of lifetimes of an array of machines without information about when the machines were first turned on?

Answer (score 1):

**I assumed $t$ and $t′$, the observed and un-observed times, were independent.**

let $t'$ = The unknown age achieved without failure.

let $\Delta$ = additional hours to operate.

- if you assume your failure distribution is uniform then, time is irrelevant always. (No matter what the values of times are, probability of failure is always same which is unrealistic.) $t'$ and $\Delta$ are irrelevant for this case.
- if you assume your failure distribution is exponential then, the exponential distribution is memoryless because the past has no bearing on its future behavior. This means that probability of failure from $t1=0$ to $t2=\Delta+t1$ is same with probability of failure from $t3>0$ to $t4=\Delta+t3$. The exponential distribution only cares for $\Delta$ that is duration without any aging effect. So again you don't need to concern for the unknown $t'$ value.

**Do I have enough information to estimate the probability of lifetimes of an array of machines without information about when the machines were first turned on?**

you should search for distribution fitting/parameter estimation with **right censored** data.

By the way, if a machine of yours is a repairable system in contrast of a light bulb (a remove/replace item) then take extra caution if you'll take some serious real life decisions.

**... I believe the problem is that I assumed t and t′, the observed and un-observed times, were independent.**

I think you're right. You can't assume $t$ and $t′$ are independent in all boundary of reliability theory. Statistical analyses based on $t$ and $t′$ are mostly dependent. You may consider to search for **conditional reliability function** to arrive to **conditional unreliability function** (or **conditional cumulative distribution function**) if you are unaware of.

A recommended book if you have access: *Probability Distributions Used in Reliability Engineering; Andrew N. O’Connor*